# ubuntu terminal & operator

Tags: command-line, bash

What does the following command do:

```
COMM1 & COMM2
```

and how is it different from:

```
COMM1 && COMM2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
COMM1 & COMM2
```

launches `COMM1` as a [background process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process) and immediately executes `COMM2`; whereas

```
COMM1 && COMM2
```

waits for `COMM1` to finish, and then executes `COMM2` if and only if `COMM1` completed successfully.

Technically, `&&` is a [short-circuit logical operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) which is evaluating the second statement only if it cannot determine the logical value of the combined expression otherwise: in other words, if the exit status of `COMM1` is *true*, then `COMM2` must be evaluated, but if the exit status of `COMM1` is *false*, then there is no need to evaluate `COMM2` since the expression as a whole cannot be true.

Answer (score 0):

when using `&&` it means, that a script/command must wait until the first execution is successfully fired off before being able to proceed with 2nd script/command.  For example,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

With this command, it means that update will be fired first and upgrade have to wait until update is done before it can proceed.

just only `&` it means, whatever command/script you entered, all of them will be executed in the background and will act independently from other each other (multi-commands/scripts).